# Git: error: src refspec master does not match any even after running git commit -m

Tags: git

After running `git init`, `git add .`, `git commit -m "Test"`, and finally `git push origin master --force`, I still get the following error:

> error: src refspec master does not match any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing git push -u origin master do:
`git remote add origin <repo_git>`
If using github, repo git will be:
https://github.com/username/reponame.git
Or just click on the code button on your github repo and copy the link.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue persists even after "git remote add origin <repo_git>", then try commit as below and the run the push command again, the issue should be resolved.

git commit -m "initial commit" --allow-empty